# Sort Characters By Frequency Java (Optimal Solution)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, hashmap

I'm trying to solve this question using Java. The goal is to sort a string in decreasing order based on the frequency of characters. For example "Aabb" is going to be "bbaA" or "bbAa". I have implemented a working solution but it's in O(n^2). I was wondering if someone out there has a better and more optimal solution.
Here is the code:

```
public class Solution 
{
    public String frequencySort(String s) 
   {
    Map<Character,Integer> map =new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        if(map.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))
            map.put(s.charAt(i),map.get(s.charAt(i))+1);
        else
            map.put(s.charAt(i),1);
    }

    List<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>> sortedlist = new ArrayList<>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(sortedlist, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Character,Integer>>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o1,
            Map.Entry<Character, Integer> o2) {
        return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
    }
    });

    String lastString="";
    for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer>  e : sortedlist) 
    {
        for(Integer j=0;j <  e.getValue();j++)
           lastString+= e.getKey().toString();
    }
    return lastString;
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, technically this isn't `O(n ^ 2)`. And there may be a few minor optimizations possible here, but there's no way to get below `O(n log n)`, where you are already.

Comment: @Paul so there is no way in Java to do this better? https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-characters-by-frequency/ is not accepting this answer because of time limitation

Comment: Sure there are ways to improve the code. Replace `Map<Character,Integer>` with `Map<Character,int[]>` so you can update integer value using `++` instead of unboxing and reboxing `Integer` objects. If running Java 8, use the `merge()` method. Don't do `string += string`, but use a `StringBuilder`. And for same reason as above, change loop to `int`, not `Integer`. To create a string of N times the same letter, create a `char[N]` and use `Arrays.fill()` to assign the letter to all elements.

Comment: Have you considered a treemap? it will autosort for you, though i'm not entirely sure if it's faster or not

Comment: @HiradRoshandel Well, there's no algorithm with better time-complexity (assuming your hashmap works in `O(1)`. This doesn't mean your code can't be optimized. It means you won't be able to improve asymptotic time-complexity, but there are plenty of ways to improve this code.

Comment: @zack6849 TreeMap will sort by *key*, but this needs to be sorted by *value*, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't pass because of string concatenation, use StringBuilder instead and I bet you will pass.

```
StringBuilder builder = bew StringBuilder();
builder.append(e.getKey());

return builder.toString();
```

There are a couple of other ideas how to sort elements by frequency.

1. Use a sorting algorithm to sort the elements O(nlogn)
2. Scan the sorted array and construct a 2D array of element and count
   O(n).
3. Sort the 2D array according to count O(nlogn)

   Input 2 5 2 8 5 6 8 8

   After sorting we get
     2 2 5 5 6 8 8 8

   Now construct the 2D array as

   2, 2

   5, 2

   6, 1

   8, 3

   Sort by count

   8, 3

   2, 2

   5, 2

   6, 1

[copyright](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-elements-by-frequency/)

Follow the link to take a look at other possible approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm is actually `O(n)` (thanks [@andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas), twice!):

- Building the map of counts is `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the input
- Sorting the list of entries is `O(m log m)`, where `m` is the number of unique characters in the input
- Rebuilding the sorted string is `O(n)`

Although the slowest step by magnitude may appear to be the sorting, most probably it isn't the dominant operation when the input is very large. "Probably", because `m` is bound by the size of the alphabet, which is normally expected to be much smaller than the size of a very large input. Hence the overall time complexity of `O(n)`.

Some minor optimizations are possible, but won't change the order of complexity:

- You can first get a character array from the input string. It uses more memory, but you will save the boundary checks of `.charAt`, and the array can be useful at a later step (see below).
- If you know the size of the alphabet, then you can use an `int[]` instead of a hash map.
- Instead of rebuilding the sorted string manually and with string concatenation, you could write into the character array and return `new String(chars)`.

Comment: Sorting the list is not `O(n log n)`, but `O(m log m)` where `m` is the number of unique characters, i.e. `m <= n`. As `n` rises to very high numbers, `m` will plateau at a point that depends on language, e.g. for English it will flatten out around 60 (26 lowercase letter + 26 uppercase letter + 1 space + some punctuation characters). As such, the sort becomes immaterial, and algorithm is just `O(n)`.

Comment: Up-vote for suggesting a full `char[]` in the last bullet. That is an even better solution than using `StringBuilder`. And reusing the array from first step is just icing on the cake.

Comment: Thanks Andreas for the precision (and the upvote), I was just lazy to spell it out, but you're right, it's important to mention.

Comment: You missed the point of the last sentence. The overall algorithm is `O(n)`, since `O(m log m)` becomes a constant at high `n` values, and is hence eliminated from the equation. Think `n = 100000` (linear), with `m = 60` (constant).

Comment: @Andreas I'm not sure if it's running in O(n). https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-characters-by-frequency/ is rejecting my solution due to time limitation. I understand your point though

Comment: @HiradRoshandel note that there can be difference between `O(n)` and `O(n)` too. If you implement some or all of the optimization steps, your solution will surely pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to display the characters according to their frequency, we can use a map or dictionary in Python.
I am solving this using Python:

```
# sort characters by frequency

def fix(s): 
    d = {}
    res=""
    for ch in a: d[ch] = d.get(ch,0)+1
    # use this lambda whenever you have to sort with values
    for val in sorted(d.items(),reverse = True,key = lambda ch : ch[1]):
        res = res + val[0]*val[1]
    return res    


a = "GiniGinaProtijayi"
print(fix(a))
```

Method 2 :Using collections.Counter().most_common()

```
# sort characeters by frequency
a = "GiniGinaProtijayi"


def sortByFrequency(a):
    aa = [ch*count  for ch, count in collections.Counter(a).most_common()]
    print(aa)
    print(''.join(aa))


sortByFrequency(a)
```